# Multiple visual studio emulator for android errors

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I cannot run visual studio emulator for android. I'm getting this error when pressing green play button on device profile:

> We encountered a problem while launching this device. Please try again
>   or see log file for details.

Here is the log:

```
26.08.2015 22:24:32: [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
26.08.2015 22:24:32: [Informational] Launching Device: 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone
26.08.2015 22:24:32: [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
26.08.2015 22:24:32: [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
26.08.2015 22:24:32: [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
26.08.2015 22:24:33: [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' device.
26.08.2015 22:24:33: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
26.08.2015 22:24:33: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5 /video "1080x1920" /vhd "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5_KitKat_(4.4)_XXHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.александр" /noStart /silent
26.08.2015 22:24:33: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: InvalidArguments (3)
```

Windows Phone emulator works perfect. Repairing and reinstalling the emulator did not help. Checked, that I am a member of Hyper-V Administrators group.

UPD1:
I managed to run the emulator anyway. I launched it from command prompt without 2 last parameters: "/noStart /silent". Then I saw a dialog about configuring the internet connection and pressed "NO". And the emulator successfully launched.
Perhaps the problem is somewhere in Hyper-V manager -> virtual switches? I have 10 equal virtual switches there, and cannot remove them: "Fail while removing virtual Ethernet switch".

UPD2:
Now, my unity3d application doesn't work. I deploy it by drag'n'drop, then press it's icon and black screen appears. Is it because of emulator internet connection error?

Answer (score 2):

The third argument is in the Name.

5\"

```
/sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone"
```

Change the name in 
C:\Users\windowsuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\xxxxx_Phone.cfg

```
device.name=MyDevice (4.4)
```

Comment: Changed name from 
device.name=5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone 
to 
device.name=5.7\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone
Solved the problem

Comment: This worked for me, however it removes the emulator from the list of emulators in Visual Studio, any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with a new Windows 10 install with VS 2015. This is a VM running on a Mac in Parallels.

This is the informative part of the message:

`[Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5\" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 5......
26.08.2015 22:24:33: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: InvalidArguments (3)`

The third argument is "memSize 2048", so I increased the RAM for my VM from 2 GB to 4 GB and the emulator could launch.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure, where i can increase RAM in hyper-v in windows 10. But I managed to run the emulator anyway. Look at "UPD1".

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart your computer after you install the emulator in order to apply the changes that enable you to work with virtual switches. If all else fails, remove all switches via the Device Manager in Windows and start an emulator again (allowing it to recreate these switches).

Comment: I removed all switches in "Network Adapters" section in device manager, then launched Visual Studio Emulator for Android again and chose 5" KitKat device. "Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter" appeared in "Network Adapters" section, but emulator progress bar stopped in the middle again and result is the same: when I press stop and play again I get this error: "[Critical] XDE Exit Code: InvalidArguments (3)"

Comment: Are you still pressing "no" on the dialogue about configuring the internet? The emulator needs you to hit "yes" for it to configure the switches properly.

Comment: No, i'm pressing standard "play" button in UI, not in command line.